# broadcast receiver not receiving intent only on Samsung Galaxy s4 mobile

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am facing a weird problem .

I have a Broadcast receiver inside fragment which is notified when login process is complete . 
The code works on all the mobile phones but does not work on Samsung Galaxy S4 . 
The broadcast receiver is not receiving any messages at all.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver loginReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null) {
            if (UbiWebApiConstants.ACTION_LOGIN_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
```

onReceive method is not called at all . 
The broadcast event is being sent for sure.

Can somebody help me .

Thanks

Comment: where in fragment life cycle is your receiver getting registered / unregistered?

Comment: onResume() i am registering the receiver and onPause() i am unregistering receiver

Comment: If i have the broadcast in activity it is receiving messages but not if its inside fragment . And this is only on samsung galaxy s4

Comment: which context are you using to register the receiver? is it the parent activity?

Comment: yes i am using parent activity context   getActivity().registerReceiver(loginReceiver,new IntentFilter(UbiWebApiConstants.ACTION_LOGIN_COMPLETE));